# Using CSS :before, Justified Text Look

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to use the CSS :before property to append a word in front of a regular paragraph. I want the remainder of the paragraph to be justified left, so that there is a margin underneath the appended word.

In order to achieve this effect, I've needed to set the height of the :before to an arbitrary height. But, if I don't know how much text will be in the actual paragraph, I have no idea what height I need to in the declaration.

```
.prereq:before {
    content:"Prerequisite: ";
    font-weight:700;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding-right:30px;
    height:70px;
}
```

The attached jFiddle might help better explain what I am trying to do.
http://jsfiddle.net/fgpj8w74/7/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What if you just remove `height` instead?

Comment: @raina77ow, then probably the paragraph text would come under the *Prerequisite:*, as it is a `float`

Comment: Does the "prerequisite" word ever change, so you don't know how wide it is? Otherwise you might not need floats...

Comment: How about [this approach](http://jsfiddle.net/pcwakxdr/) then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fgpj8w74/11/)

You can work with `table-cell`'s so you wont concern about `float` or `height`, since they will fit each other automatically.

Just make your `.prereq` element a `display: table`, and the pseudo one a `display: table-cell`:

```
.prereq {
    display: table;
}

.prereq:before {
    content:"Prerequisite: ";
    font-weight:700;
    display:table-cell;
    padding-right:30px;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it, but [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgpj8w74/9/) shows it in action.

Comment: The CSS is a bit broken (`.prereq` is `table-row`, `.prereq:before` is `table-cell`, but the content is NOT `table-cell`) so cross-browser may not work.

Comment: Cool, I think that `table-row` for `.prereq`: Each is  a row in the table, rather than table in itself

Comment: It will also work better in cases when you have things besides `.prereq` : http://jsfiddle.net/fgpj8w74/12/

Comment: Completely awesome. The table & table-cell approaches look like they'll do the trick. Props for all those who helped shape the answer. :-)